# What is the next number and why? - 11,21,1112,…

Tags: number-sequence

Simple logic question, what is the next number and why?

11, 21, 1112, 3112, 211213, 312213, 212223, 114213, ?

Comment: This is something like the 5th version of this sequence (allowing for variations for order of digits) in the last few days... did this sort of puzzle get published somewhere recently?

Comment: Go here at $5$:$33$, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5P-f5arPXE

Answer (score 1):

This is a repeat of one on the front page but,

> The answer is 31121314, each number is counting the quantity of numbers before it in increasing magnitude. (Three ones, one two, one three, one four).

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw it on the front page.

Comment: Which question is it / no vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: I added a duplicate vote.